# does bigger SWAP partition area helps faster "Suspend \ hibernate "?

Tags: suspend, hibernate, swap

When I suspend my computer it stores everything on RAM on hard-disk and reloads it back to RAM when I start my computer again does this data gets stored in SWAP area ? will having a 1 GB swap partition going to help lower suspend and resume time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a larger swap partition will not boost performance. When you suspend / hibernate, you copy the information RAM <--> Swap, so performance is dependent on the quantity of information you are working with, not the size of the swap.

Comment: Bodhi is right. More swap is mainly an advantage if you sometimes run out of memory and for whatever reason can't/haven't installed more RAM. But in this case, more RAM is better performance-wise.

Comment: Suspend[-to-RAM] does not a swap at all

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb is to have at least as much swap as memory (for hibernate in particular).